# Return JSON data from php with AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax, csv

i'm a newbie with AJAX .. i want to return JSON data from php.

here is my code php where i want to convert csv file to json data

```
    <?php
function getcsv(){
//Open our CSV file using the fopen function.
    $fh = fopen("taxe.csv", "r");

//Setup a PHP array to hold our CSV rows.
    $csvData = array();

//Loop through the rows in our CSV file and add them to
//the PHP array that we created above.
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $csvData[] = $row;
    }

//Finally, encode our array into a JSON string format so that we can print it out.
    return json_encode($csvData);
}
?>
```

and this my script :

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'CalculTaxeBienvenue.php',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("ok");
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But i had this result :

[image]

Any help please

Comment: I’m not seeing a call to `getcsv();` in your PHP file 

Comment: @matigo where and how to do this ? in php file or js file ?

Comment: In your PHP file. You are defining a function, but never calling it.